# How do I write only the matching regex to a new file in Python?

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to extract the IP Addresses only and append them to a new file.
The file I have is called error_log.txt and has lines such as:

> [Sun Jun  7 16:45:56 2020] [info] [client 64.242.88.10] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed

> [Sun Jun 7 17:13:50 2020] [info] [client 64.242.88.10] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed

The goal is to write "64.242.88.10" and the rest of the IPs to a new file.

I can get the print function to give me only the IPs, but when it writes to the file 'ip_only.txt' it prints the complete line from the error log.

How can I just get the IPs only to the new file (in a column)?

Bonus, when it does print when testing, it gives me the blank lines too. How can I omit those lines?

```
import re

with open('error_log.txt', 'r') as file:
    fi = file.readlines()

ip_only = open('ip_only.txt', 'w+')

re_ip = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")

for line in fi:
    ip = re.findall(re_ip, line)
    ip_only.write(str(line))
    # print(ip)
```

Comment: why do you `write(line)` if you need `write(ip)` ?

Comment: to skip empty strings `if ip.strip() != "":` or shorter `if not ip.strip():`

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the `ip` variable to the file instead of `line` which contains the original line:

```
for line in fi:
    ip = re.findall(re_ip, line)
    ip_only.write(str(ip))

# ip_only.txt:
# ['64.242.88.10']['64.242.88.10']
```

Additionally, to remove the brackets and quotes from your output (note that  `re.findall()` returns a list of strings) and print each IP address to a new line:

```
for line in fi:
    ips = re.findall(re_ip, line)
    for ip in ips:
        ip_only.write(ip + '\n')

# ip_only.txt:
# 64.242.88.10
# 64.242.88.10
```

Comment: this code change creates a blank file, but is not writing any lines right now.

Comment: That's odd, I have tested it in my local environment with the error log lines you provided and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. While writing into file, you are writing the whole line. instead write only the IPs as below
   `ip_only.write(str(ip))`
2. To avoid blank lines, you can have a if condition to check, whether the ip is found or not in the given line.

```
   for line in fi:
       ip = re.findall(re_ip, line)
       if ip:
           ip_only.write(str(ip))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `print(ip)` gives you expected result then you should use `write(ip)` instead of `write(line)`

regex gives list so you may need to write only `ip[0]`. And you need to add `\n` to move to the next line.

```
        ip_only.write(ip[0] + "\n")
```

As for empty line - first remove all spaces, tabs, enters and next compare with empty string `""`. OR use fact that empty string gives `False` when used in `if/else`

```
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
         # ... code ...
```

---

```
import re

fi = [
    '[Sun Jun 7 16:45:56 2020] [info] [client 64.242.88.10] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
    '[Sun Jun 7 17:13:50 2020] [info] [client 64.242.88.10] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
]    


ip_only = open('ip_only.txt', 'w+')

re_ip = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")

for line in fi:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        ip = re.findall(re_ip, line)
        ip_only.write(ip[0] + "\n")
        print(ip[0])
```